# Java play onRouteRequest - how to return an answer?

Tags: java, ajax, redirect, playframework, routes

I'm using java-play 2.2.1.
I created JS code that send AJAX GET request with a url address that doesn't exist in the conf/routes file. It would be complicated to describe why i don't want to declare this URL at the routes file, so just take it as fact :) .
I catch this request by overriding `OnRouteRequest`
function (by creating Global object..), and i pull the get params from the request query string (because it's a GET request) and create an object (hashtable) i want to return to the AJAX code at the client-side. Unfortunately, `OnRouteRequest` function returns `Handler`.

I'm really desperate right now from this issue, if anyone has any idea how can i do it, it would be really great. Even if anyone knows how to redirect from `OnRouteRequest` to another action which will return after to the AJAX it would be great. Thanks !

Comment: have you looked at the source code for the original `OnRouteRequest` to see how it sets the response?  I don't know anything about this "play framework", but the design of this request handling function (method) you describe sounds similar to the design of Servlets (JavaEE).  In servlets, you don't "return" the response, you get a `Stream` from the request and then write to it.  *Then* you return (or pass the call your parent servlet).  Does this help?  Please consider posting some code in your question.

Comment: Yes, you can can write to your stream and pass the call to your parent method) but the parent method is trying to find the request url at the routes file, and of course , as i said above, it wont find it there. So again, how can i redirect this request directly to another method without going through routes file?

Comment: @user3660790, have you tried onHandlerNotFound method to return what you want?